# How to skip row of data if condition is met in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to skip row in laravel where the condition is met. Please see my code below.

**What I need**

I want to skip or exclude all data with 'Male' gender and where network is 'Elite'.

**Controller**

```
$users = User::where('active', 1)
  ->leftJoin('profile', 'users.id', '=', 'profile.user_id')
  ->groupBy('users.id');

if(request('status') == 7) {
  $users->where('profile.gender', '!=', 'Male')->where('profile.network', 'Elite');
}

return $users->get();
```

Laravel v5.2

**Update: for possible solution**

*This solution is when I use foreach but what I need is inside the query so still not the solution.*

```
$data = [];
foreach($users as $user) {
  if(
    $status == 7 && 
    $user->profile->gender != 'Male' && 
    $user->profile->city == 'NY'
  ){
    continue;
  }

  $data[] = $user->id;
}
```

Comment: you might need to do `$users = $users->where('profile.gender',` inside the if condition.

Comment: @user3532758 Can you add your answer?

Comment: @Jonjie What do you mean by **skip**? Are you trying to query all of the data and then select the desired ones or filter data in your query?

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI Filter the data in query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use compound where statement like:

```
$users = User::where('active', 1)
  ->where('gender', '!=' ,'Male')
  ->leftJoin('profile', 'users.id', '=', 'profile.user_id')
  ->groupBy('users.id');
```

Comment: Please add explanation and reference if possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(request('status') == 7) {
      $users->whereNotIn('profile.gender', ['Male'])->where('profile.network', 'Elite');
    }
```

Comment: I think this code won't give different result as my code above since you're also getting users where not 'Male' not skipping them.

Comment: @Jonjie they are trying to exclude those records with the `whereNotIn`